# Como limpiar un select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formularios

Tengo un formalario y cuando envio la información para hacer un `POST` estoy limpiando el form con un `setForm(initialForm);` . Esto limpia todos los campos menos el select que se queda con la ultima opción seleccionada y lo que deseo es que vuelva a su valor por default que es 'Elegir temperamento'

```
            <select
              name="temperaments"
              defaultValue="default"
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
            >
              <option value="default">Elegir temperamento</option>
              {temperaments?.map(t => (
                <option value={t.name} key={t.id}>
                  {t.name}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
```

Comment: Tal vez con el metodo remove se pueda pero, no se si se pueda usar Jquery con react

Answer (score 0):

Para esto, podes agregar un valor por defecto al elemento select haciendo que el atributo defaultValue sea el valor de la opción por defecto, en este caso "default". Esto establecerá el valor por defecto del elemento select en la opción por defecto cuando se renderice el formulario.

Para resetear el elemento select al valor por defecto cuando se resetee el formulario, podes establecer el atributo value del elemento select en el valor por defecto en la función setForm. Esto sobrescribirá el valor actual del elemento select y lo establecerá en el valor por defecto.

```
<select
  name="temperaments"
  defaultValue="default"
  value={form.temperaments}
  onChange={handleChange}
  onBlur={handleBlur}
>
  <option value="default">Elegir temperamento</option>
  {temperaments?.map(t => (
    <option value={t.name} key={t.id}>
      {t.name}
    </option>
  ))}
</select>

// en la función setForm
setForm({
  ...initialForm,
  temperament: 'default'
});
```

Espero y te ayude o al menos guie, cualquier cosa, consulta. Exitos